# GCC Loop optimization

Tags: disassembly

I have been looking at some simple C code and the different output from GCC using different optimization levels.

**C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;

    while(i<10) {
            printf("Hello\n");
            i++;
    }

    i = 0;

    while(i<10) {
            printf("i: %d\n", i);
            i++;
    }
```

}

When I compile the code using `-Os` or `-O2` the first loop works a bit differently. It it decrements instead of incrementing, and it is in two different ways. I am wondering why it decrements instead of incrementing like in the code, and the the small difference between `-Os` and `-O2`.

**-Os compiled**

```
0x400486 <main+6>       mov     edi,0x40068c
0x40048b <main+11>      call    0x400450 <puts@plt>
0x400490 <main+16>      dec     ebx
0x400492 <main+18>      jne     0x400486 <main+6>
```

**-O2 compiled**

```
0x400490 <main+16>      mov    edi,0x40069c
0x400495 <main+21>      call   0x400450 <puts@plt>
0x40049a <main+26>      sub    ebx,0x1
0x40049d <main+29>      jne    0x400490 <main+16>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By decrementing, compiler can make use of `jne` (jump if not equal/zero) which does the comparison (to zero) and jump in a single instruction. In case of incrementing, it would have to do a `cmp/test` (with 10) and then a conditional jump like `jnz/jne`. I believe it is a part of optimization.

`-Os` flag optimizes to bring down the code size. The code generated using `-Os` uses `dec ebx` instead of `sub ebx, 0x1`, since `dec ebx` is a 2-byte instruction while `sub ebx, 0x1` is a 3-byte instruction (Note the address at which the next instruction begins). That explains the small difference.

Comment: This does explain the difference in one direction, but not the other; it seems that there must be an advantage of `sub` over `dec` otherwise O2 would not have chosen it.

Comment: With a little research I think I found the reason why **O2** uses **sub** instead of **dec**. [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) In table C-19 in appendix C **add/sub** has a lower latency.

Answer (score 5):

Because I can't comment, I'll try to fix some inaccuracies in pnak4j's answer.

`dec ebx` is really a 1-byte instruction (I don't know why it appears to be 2-bytes). `DEC` sets the `ZF` flag accordingly to the result of (`ebx-1`) when: zero or not zero. Then, `JNE` does the jump if not zero (`JNE`/`JNZ` are the same). `JMP` is not a conditional jump, therefore it would not make much sense after `CMP`/`TEST`.

Comment: By `jmp`, I meant a conditional jump. An unconditional jump doesn't make much sense after a compare. It has been edited. Thanks.

Comment: `dec ebx` is `0xff 0xcb`